# Get DotNetNuke Text Editor HTML Value with JQUERY / Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, dotnetnuke

I'd like to get DNN Text Editor's value from client side jQuery or javascript.
I could retrieve the element by id but I'm nowhere close to get the value / content of the text editor. Can anyone show me a way or an alternative way to achieve this?

With the help of this [link](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/answers/how-can-i-get-set-dnn-texteditor-control-from-client-side), I could only manage to get the id as below but when I tried to console out, it's 'undefined'.

```
var txt = $('#<%= ResourceText.ClientID %>_ResourceText');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following: `$('#<%= ResourceText.ClientID %>_ResourceText').val()`

Comment: it's the get only.. how to set text using jQuery?